# Timeline events paging, Architecture

Tags: php, oop

I am having a bit of a problem with events. I have several different type of events, and by that i mean tasks, meetings, calls, comments and there may have other in future.

All of them have time of creation and i need to get them to a timeline representation. But because they may be many of them i better page them or load say 20-30 of them and a button for load more.

The problem is i need to get say 20, and arrange them by time but they can be any collection. They are not the same data structure so are not in 1 table in db. Nor i keep some notion of which one is before which other other than time.

I don't want to get say 20 of each and then arrange them by time and free not needed.

Code is irrelevant i think because its more architecture problem than actually doin it.

One last thing, they are bond to an object - say client, but the bond is not 1:1 and bond is not only to that kind of object. There is a company object that has clients, and in some point can inherit their events and show them, combined with its own events, again arranging it by time.

Comment: You could do a union of the tables in the database and then order by event date and limit

Comment: Yes, thx man. Kind of obvious, guess i was stuck. I can even abstract the union so new type of events wont bother the rest

Comment: What you have is called polymorphism, a kind of inheritance for relational data. Some PHP frameworks support it. E.g. if you have a single `events` table with an `event_type` column with values like "call", "task" etc and then in the framework you can have a class for each event type and have the row "morph" into the appropriate class. I personally would prefer this solution, but for some this goes against the very idea of relational data.

Comment: That is optional solution of course. But implies that the solution ready so far have to be reinvented. Morphing solution is get say 5 properties(id, date, creator, etc.) that are common for all events as rows in DB and put all rest as an object data in a serialized variable(actual object). Then all the work is done in the business logic itself which gives it behavior. What i don't like there is mixing it. That part of the solution and different logic in it will be a problem in general sense in my view. But I like the idea of it. :)